# Querying Amazon Web Services RDS via Google App engine Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, java-7, amazon-rds

Querying Amazon Web Services RDS via Google App engine Standard Environment seems to be very slow and is proportional to number of records that are being fetched.
For example, if the query returns one record, it takes 100ms and if it returns 10 records, it takes 1 sec. This is slowing our apis down a lot.

Has anyone else faced this? If yes, what have you to done to sort the issue?

PS: We were on google-cloud-sql prior to migrating to aws rds. Migrating due to financial constraints.

Comment: Does not sound like normal performance to me. I have not used in production this combination but in some test cases I have tried and had no problems. How is the connection and authentication handled in your setup? What about other setup and table structure? What is the performance if you query from AWS e.g. from EC2?

Comment: It is pretty quick from EC2 and the time taken isn't proportional to number of records. GAE takes time though. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: What language and client libraries do you use in GAE?